# Can I code this polynomial equation with unknown parameter?

Tags: python, matlab, sympy, mql4, mql5

I am trying to code an equation series as follows:
Starting with Value[0],

```
the first result (Return[1]) = RR * Riskpc * Value[0], Value[1] = Value[0] + Return[1]
Return[2] = RR * ((k * Riskpc * Value[1]) + Return[1]), Value[2] = Value[1] + Return[2]
...
Return[n] = RR * ((k * Riskpc * Value[n-1]) + Return[n-1]), Value[n] = Value[n-1] + Return[n]
```

this is effectively limiting the loss of the whole series to Riskpc*Value while adding (a multiplier (k) * the whole of the previous return) to the amount risked.

I need to be able to code this in python and in mql4 and mql5 so that regardless of n, Value[n] == m * Value[0], m being a constant > 1. In the current problem m = 1.101, RR = 3 and Riskpc = 1.

I understand that the solution is a geometric equation such that for any given series of length n (n > 1) with constants RR Riskpc and m, k is a function of RR, Riskpc, n and m but this is way beyond my 30 yr old A level maths.

I have tried to explore matlab and sympy but have got lost...

**Edit**

Sorry I realise the original question was too vague.
My colab file is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/132jeFaPxisaeCVe-Mlv2tL5M_qbE9x-P?usp=sharing).

It works for `compoundLength = 2` as per the defaults in that file, but for `compoundLength = 3+` it will only reduce risk on the last trade.

In there I am trying to program the `calcRisk()` function to replace the logic in lines 56 and 51 such that the partial preservation of previous returns is spread across the series (not including the first trade) rather than only occurring on the last trade.

*The original problem was:* with a reward:risk ratio of 3, by adding the return on the first trade to the 1% of the new account value as the risk for the second trade (so as to increase upside potential whilst not losing more than the initial 1% across the 2 trades), how do I limit the risk placed on the second trade to that neccessary to hit the target of 10.1%?

This is achieved in a series of 2 by the logic at line 56 and preserves around 50% (depending on previous drawdown) of the returns from trade 1.

The object is to extend this to n (`compoundLength`) trades. The monte-carlo simulator runs 1,000,000 possible trade series, calculating the reduced cumulative risk on the next trade after every profitable trade, but on series of 3+, as it stands, all the benefit of the reduced risk is only realised on the last trade.

Comment: This has little to do with maths, either A level or PhD. Its just a for loop, isnt it?

Comment: No because the length of the geometric equation lengthens as n increases as does the exponential. n is unknown - I can code it for a known value of n but not for an unknown value. If you think otherwise offer me the code...

Comment: No it does not, you just need to compute the previous value, and then substitute it in the next iteration. You don't write the equation, you just evaluate `Return[1]` and use that to evaluate `Return[2]` in the next loop iteration. Try to write a program to compute the fibonnaci number `n`, then just change the equation to your equation.

Comment: Fibonacci is a single order equation. This involves a progressive exponential equation

Comment: Your equation is literally, in code: `r[i] = RR * ((k * Riskpc * v[i-1]) + r[i-1]); v[i] = v[i-1] + r[i];` Just add a loop for `i`.  There isnt an exponential in the equations you shared.

Comment: I am trying to get v as a function of n programmatically. I can write your code easy enough.

Comment: Sorry, Ander. Please see the OP edit

Comment: I still don't know understand why the loop does not work, but if you want an explicit formula for  `f(Value[0],n,RR,Riskpc)` then you will need to indeed solve it by hand (if its possible). But stackoverflow is not a place for hand-solving math problems. Most of the standard type of series have an explicit solution that is stated in wikipedia, e.g. Geometric series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward implementation in python:

```
def f(n):
  from sympy import symbols, Tuple
  assert n > 0
  v0, RR, Riskpc, k = symbols('v0 RR Riskpc k')
  Value = v0
  _Return = RR * Riskpc * v0
  for i in range(1, n + 1):
    Return = _Return
    Value += Return
    _Return = RR * ((k * Riskpc * Value) + Return)
  return Tuple(Value, Return)
```

It returns the symbolic values of the nth term for `Value` and `Return`; you can used to substitute in known values, e.g.

```
>>> f(3).subs({RR: 3, Riskpc: 1})
(48*k*v0 + 3*k*(12*k*v0 + 13*v0) + 40*v0, 36*k*v0 + 3*k*(12*k*v0 + 13*v0) + 27*v0)
>>> from sympy import factor
>>> list(map(factor, _))
[v0*(36*k**2 + 87*k + 40), 3*v0*(12*k**2 + 25*k + 9)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will test in next few days - but it looks very promising, and something close to what i thought i was searching for!!

Comment: Hmmm still not getting where I want to be. The equation series is v1 == v0+v0*RR*y,v2 == v1*RR*y+(v1-v0)*RR*y,v3 == v2*RR*y+(v2-v1)*RR*y ... vn == v(n-1)*RR*y+(v(n-1)-v(n-2))*RR*y, and I need to be able to calculate y when v0,vn,RR,and n are known